# Get maximum values of a multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm trying to find the maximum values of a multidimensional array.

Input:

```
[[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]
```

Result:

```
[5, 27, 39, 1001]
```

What I've tried:

```
var largestArr = [];

function largestOfFour(arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var largest = 0;
    var currentArr = arr[i];
    var stop = currentArr.length;
    for (var j = 0; j < stop; j++) {
      if (currentArr[0] > largest) {
        largest = currentArr[0];
        largestArr.push(largest);
        largestArr.shift();
      }
    }

    return largestArr;
  }
}

largestOfFour([
  [4, 5, 1, 3],
  [13, 27, 18, 26],
  [32, 35, 37, 39],
  [1000, 1001, 857, 1]
]);
```

Can anyone help me understand why this isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here

```
if (currentArr[0]>largest){
   largest = currentArr[0];
   //
}
```

This should be done like below:

```
if (currentArr[j]>largest){
    largest = currentArr[j];
    // 
}
```

> Why this is wrong?

This is wrong because you always compare the first item of each array with the `largest` and not all the items in each array one after the other.

Furthermore, you have to make a few more corrections.

Specifficaly, there isn't any need to use the `shift` method. You have only to push the largest value of each array after the end of each processing in the `largestArr`. Last, but not least you have to move the return statement of the `largestArr` out of the for loops.

```js
var largestArr = [];

function largestOfFour(arr) {
  for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    var largest = 0;
    var currentArr = arr[i];
    var stop = currentArr.length;
    for (var j=0; j<stop; j++){
      if (currentArr[j]>largest){
        largest = currentArr[j];
      }
    }
    largestArr.push(largest); 
  }
  return largestArr;
}

alert(largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the answer has been provided here's some code can do the same job in a smaller number of lines that you might find useful in the future using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

```
var out = arr.reduce(function (p, c) {
  return p.concat(Math.max.apply(null, c));
}, []);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/44qskv97/)

Answer (score 0):

Christos' answer is correct and should the selected as answer.

Additionally though, you should not pollute the global namespace by declaring `largestArray` outside of the function, considering that you are returning said array anyway.

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
    var largestArr = [];       // put this line here instead of making it global
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        var largest = 0;
        var currentArr = arr[i];
        var stop = currentArr.length;
        for (var j=0; j<stop; j++){
            if (currentArr[j]>largest){
                largest = currentArr[0]; 
            }
        }
        largestArr.push(largest);
    }
    return largestArr;
}

largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```